# Slick slider YouTube glitch on last and first slide

Tags: jquery, youtube, slider, carousel, slick.js

I'm trying to implement a [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) which contains an infinite looping series of Youtube videos which autoplay and pause when swiping to the next slide etc. I also wanted to be able to swipe the videos like you can with images.

I have this working but I'm noticing a problem when sliding from the last slide to the first slide. Rather than just pausing, the last and first videos pause but then display the video cover image, instead of just pausing.

Here's my html...

```
<div class="slider-youtube">
    <div class="item youtube">
        <div class="video-background">
            <div class="video-foreground">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M-hGwtvtXCk?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;loop=1&playlist=M-hGwtvtXCk&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-button">
            <a href="#">SEE MORE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item youtube">
        <div class="video-background">
            <div class="video-foreground">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V2vwFS8ae2I?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;loop=1&playlist=V2vwFS8ae2I&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-button">
            <a href="#">SEE MORE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item youtube">
        <div class="video-background">
            <div class="video-foreground">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YXBUD7-ACMM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;loop=1&playlist=YXBUD7-ACMM&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-button">
            <a href="#">SEE MORE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my css...

```
.slider-youtube iframe {
    min-width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
}
.slider-youtube .youtube {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.slider-youtube .youtube:not(.slick-current) {
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
img.slick-slide {
    max-width: 100vw;
}
.video-background {
    background: #000;
    z-index: -99;
    max-height: 400px;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-button {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.slick-button a {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

...and here's my javascript...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //on first load, play the video
    $(".slider-youtube").on('init', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
        var currentSlide, player, command;
        currentSlide = $(slick.$slider).find(".slick-current");
        player = currentSlide.find("iframe").get(0);
        command = {
            "event": "command",
            "func": "playVideo"
        };
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), "*");
            }, 5000);
    });
    //when new slide displays, play the video
    $(".slider-youtube").on("afterChange", function(event, slick) {
        var currentSlide, player, command;
        currentSlide = $(slick.$slider).find(".slick-current");
        player = currentSlide.find("iframe").get(0);
        command = {
            "event": "command",
            "func": "playVideo"
        };
        if (player != undefined) {
            player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), "*");
        }
    });
    //reset iframe of non current slide
    $(".slider-youtube").on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlidee) {
        var current = $('.slick-current');
        var currentSlide, player, command;
        currentSlide = $(slick.$slider).find(".slick-current");
        player = currentSlide.find("iframe").get(0);
        command = {
            "event": "command",
            "func": "pauseVideo"
        };
        if (player != undefined) {
            player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), "*");
        }
    });
    //start the slider
    $('.slider-youtube').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '50px',
        infinite: true,
        variableWidth: true
    });
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/redcoupe/b95s2bdw/).

I have tried this in latest version of IE/Firefox and Chrome and still the same thing is happening.

This is my first post so apologies if I've done anything wrong, I have tried searching for this problem already with no luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because how the Slick slider is made, to make circular sliding it clones slides at startup, so when you slide between first and last it shows cloned slide, its state is not synchronized.

I modified your example to track and synchronize currentTime of youtube player in each of cloned slides, this way you will not notice transition

HTML

```
<script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<div class="slider-youtube">
    <div class="item youtube">
        <div class="video-background">
            <div class="video-foreground">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M-hGwtvtXCk?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;loop=1&playlist=M-hGwtvtXCk&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-button">
            <a href="#">SEE MORE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item youtube">
        <div class="video-background">
            <div class="video-foreground">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V2vwFS8ae2I?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;loop=1&playlist=V2vwFS8ae2I&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-button">
            <a href="#">SEE MORE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item youtube">
        <div class="video-background">
            <div class="video-foreground">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YXBUD7-ACMM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;loop=1&playlist=YXBUD7-ACMM&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-button">
            <a href="#">SEE MORE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".slider-youtube iframe").each(function (idx) {
        $(this).addClass("data-idx-" + idx).data("idx", idx);
    });

        function getPlayer (iframe, onPlayerReady, clonned) {
            var $iframe = $(iframe);
        if ($iframe.data((clonned ? "clonned-" : "") + "player")) {
            var isReady = $iframe.data((clonned ? "clonned-" : "") + "player-ready");
          if (isReady) {
            onPlayerReady && onPlayerReady($iframe.data((clonned ? "clonned-" : "") + "player"));
          }         
            return player;
        }
        else {
            var player = new YT.Player($iframe.get(0), {
            events: {
              'onReady': function () {
                $iframe.data((clonned ? "clonned-" : "") + "player-ready", true);
                onPlayerReady && onPlayerReady(player);
              }
            }
          });        
          $iframe.data((clonned ? "clonned-" : "") + "player", player);
          return player;
        }           
    }

    //on first load, play the video
    $(".slider-youtube").on('init', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
        var currentSlide, player, command;
        currentSlide = $(slick.$slider).find(".slick-current");        
        getPlayer(currentSlide.find("iframe"), function (player) {
            player.playVideo();
        });
    });

    //when new slide displays, play the video
    $(".slider-youtube").on("afterChange", function(event, slick) {
        var currentSlide;
        currentSlide = $(slick.$slider).find(".slick-current");
        getPlayer(currentSlide.find("iframe"), function (player) {
            player.playVideo();
        });
    });

    function updateClonnedFrames () {
        frames = $(".slider-youtube").find(".slick-slide").not(".slick-cloned").find("iframe");
      frames.each(function () {
        var frame = $(this);
        var idx = frame.data("idx");
        clonedFrames = $(".slider-youtube").find(".slick-cloned .data-idx-" + idx);
        console.log("clonedFrames", frame, idx, clonedFrames);
        clonedFrames.each(function () {
            var clonnedFrame = this;
            getPlayer(frame[0], function (player) {
            getPlayer(clonnedFrame, function (clonedPlayer) {         
              console.log("clonnedPlayer", clonedPlayer);
              clonedPlayer.playVideo();  
              clonedPlayer.seekTo(player.getCurrentTime(), true);
              setTimeout(function () {
                clonedPlayer.pauseVideo();         
              }, 0);              
            }, true);
          });
        });        
      });               
    }

    //reset iframe of non current slide
    $(".slider-youtube").on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlidee) {
        var currentSlide, iframe, clonedFrame;
        currentSlide = $(slick.$slider).find(".slick-current");
        iframe = currentSlide.find("iframe");        
        getPlayer(iframe, function (player) {   
            player.pauseVideo();
          updateClonnedFrames();
        });          
    });

    //start the slider
    $('.slider-youtube').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '50px',
        infinite: true,
        variableWidth: true
    });
});
```

and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ForceUser/bst5mu3u/44/)

Comment: That works really well, I did not think of keeping track etc. Many thanks for your help. I did find a typo "currentSlidee" should be "currentSlide", just to let you know.